# How to add a heading to the left of a form in bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form in a navbar on the top of my page.

Here is the **HTML**

```
<nav id ="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right navbar-input-group" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
</nav>
```

And here is the **CSS** for the form

```
.navbar-input-group {
  font-size: 0px; 
  margin-right: 20px;

}

.navbar-input-group input {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-input-group .btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

This is what it looks like on the browser
[image]

I'd like to add some text (a heading h3) to the left of the form without this happening 
[image]

I just added a h3 element above the form...

```
<nav id ="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <h3>Text</h3>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right navbar-input-group" role="search">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
.navbar h3, .navbar form{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><h3>text</h3></li>
</ul>
```

before the form tag, if you want to add more items to your navbar. Check the examples on the http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/